# DAX - extract the date belongs to latest snapshot for each group into a new column

Tags: powerbi, dax, snapshot

I need to create a new column showing the "expiration date" that belongs to the latest snapshot for each group.

Please help with the DAX query for this new calculated column.

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a calculated column called ID

```
ID = Contracts[Contract ID] & "-" & Contracts[Year Month]
```

Then, two measures

```
MAX ID = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(Contracts[ID]),
    ALLEXCEPT(Contracts,
    Contracts[Contract ID]
    )
)
```

and

```
Latest Expire Date = LOOKUPVALUE(Contracts[Expiration Date], Contracts[ID], [MAX ID])
```

[image: ID Column]

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

For your case one column is enough ).

```
=
VAR  myID=[Contract ID]
VAR onlyGroup=
    FILTER(
        'yourTableName'
        ,'yourTableName'[Contract ID] = myID
    )
VAR lastSnSt=  MAXX(onlyGroup,[Year Month])
RETURN 
        CALCULATE(
                    MAXX(onlyGroup,[Expiration Date])
                    ,'yourTableName'[Year Month]=lastSnSt
                    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I checked, this gives the max expiration date for each contract, not the expiration date that belongs to the latest snapshot of the contract.

Comment: I added few letters ) Let me know about workability.